# Show that a regular space, under a "new" topology, is Tychonoff

Tags: general-topology

I have this problem that I can't solve it:

**Problem:** Let $(X, \tau)$ be a regular space. Let $\tau_\delta = \{A \subseteq X \, \: \, \forall a \in A \, \, \exists \, W \subseteq X \textrm{ such that } W \textrm{ is } G_\delta \textrm{ in } (X, \tau) \textrm{ and } a \in W \subseteq A\}$. Show that $(X, \tau_\delta)$ is a Tychonoff space.

I have made a lot of different topology exercises, but this is the first time that I'm asked to prove that a space is Tychonoff. Because of this, I'm having a very hard time trying to construct a continuous function that does the job.

Here is what I tried: let $x \in X$ and $F \subseteq X$ a closed set in $(X, \tau_\delta)$ such that $x \not\in F$. Now, $X \backslash F$ is open (in $(X, \tau_\delta)$) so there is a $G_{\delta}$ set of $(X, \tau)$ $W = \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} W_n$ such that $x \in W \subseteq X \backslash F$.

Each $W_n$ is open in $(X, \tau)$. By regularity, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is an open set $U_n$ such that $a \in U_n \subseteq \overline{U_n} \subseteq W_n$.

And here I'm stuck. I tried some different approaches and I had no success. I don't even know if what I did until now will lead me to the desirable function. And, because of what I said in the begginning, I have no idea of how the function should be.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: With a little more work you can choose the sets $U_n\in\tau$ so that $U_{n+1}\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_\tau U_{n+1}\subseteq U_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Now show that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}U_n$ is clopen in $\tau_\delta$, and use it to get a $\{0,1\}$-valued continuous function separating $x$ from $F$ in $\langle X,\tau_\delta\rangle$. (In case you’re not familiar with the term, *clopen* is *open and closed*.)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I solved the problem!

Comment: @user233397: Excellent; you’re welcome!